# Images don't show in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, media

I've created a content type with some custom fields, one of which is an image. When I try to render a node that contains some images uploaded like this the route is messed up, like this:

```
http://localhost/gisele-drupal//var/www/gisele-drupal/sites/default/files/contract.png
```

What can I do to configure this right?

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with you basepath.

in your .htaccess file make sure you uncomment this line

```
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /
```

and in your settings.php file you may have to change your $base_url

```
 $base_url = 'http://localhost/gisele-drupal';  // NO trailing slash!
```

let me know if that helps

Comment: does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but slightly different.
Actually i had a site and working from few months on that, was working perfectly.
today morning i saw some warning in report status in drupal 7.

so as per the guidance on  a drupal official page i uploaded an .htaccess file.

after that i noticed this issue.

after a long googling i noticed a line in .htaccess file inside default/files directory.

i.e. 
Deny from all
so i commented out this line with # only.

and my site is working fine now.